iis Timeout and Memory Leak issue
we have a website, about 20 users. the iis on the server just carries on increasing in memory usage throughout the day.
I'm checking code for memory leaks etc but have a feeling its something to do with the settings on the IIS.
We recycle the application pool 4am daily and the memory use drops dramatically.
Daily because users session variable appear to be wiped when we do it any other times.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. thanks!
iis Settings
Session State
Session State Mode Settings - In Progress
Cookie Settings - Mode : Use Cookies, Name : ASP_SessionID, Timeout in Mins : 90
Application Pool
Recyle 4am Daily
Web Config
   <authentication mode="Forms"> 
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="80" />
   </authentication>`

   <sessionState timeout="90" />

Have set Application Pool to recycle once a day due to session variables being reset.

You will have to use a debugger or profiler to see into the memory usage and tell what might be wrong.
